# Excel to calculate account balance, adding compounding daily interest

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need Excel to automatically calculate the daily interest on an amount (which will go up and down with deposits and withdrawals), and then add it to the balance total, to display the overall total including interest (compounding). This will change daily when someone looks at the value in Excel due to the daily interest being added.

For example. I have $5000. At 5% APR, the daily interest rate would be .0137%. The day after the $5000 is there, the new total should show $5000.68 if I opened and looked at the spreadsheet. Then on day 2, the total should show $5001.37. If I added $5000 more to the total on day 2 (after interest was added) I would then have $10001.37 and the interest rate for the next day should automatically add on to the new total, compounding daily.

[Sample spreadsheet with accurate balance, manually calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftqRS.png)

Essentially, I need a spreadsheet that can display the overall balance in an account which compounds daily, allowing withdrawals and deposits at anytime [Cell H2].

How do I accomplish this!? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Google sheets or excel, pick one, unless you are explicitly asking for an answer that is cross compatible only.

Comment: Then, once you have decided which, have a look on here as similar questions have been asked before.

Comment: Not sure why google sheets was selected. And I have done extensive searches for this to no avail :(